# How can I update the flow source data in android coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I am developing an android app using Coroutine.

Because I have an experience with the Rx, I can understand Coroutine Flow's concept.

But I don't know about emitting new data to the existing flow.

In Rx, I can use `BehaviorSubject` and it's `onNext()` function.

Producer:

```kotlin
class ProfileRepository(
    private val profileDao: ProfileDao
) {

    init {
        val profile = profileDao.getMyProfile()
        myProfile.onNext(profile)
    }

    val myProfile: PublishSubject<Profile> = BehaviorSubject.create()

    fun updateMyProfile(profile: Profile) {
        myProfile.onNext(profile)
    }

}
```

Subscriber:

```kotlin
class ProfileViewModel(
    private val profileRepo: ProfileRepository
) {
    val myProfile = MutableLiveData<Profile>()
    
    fun loadMyProfile() {
        profileRepo.subscribe {
            myProfile.postValue(it)
        }
    }
}
```

And other UI (like Dialog) can update the source data like:

```kotlin
class SignInDialog(
    private val profileRepo: ProfileRepository
) {
    
    fun onSignInSuccess() {
        profileRepo.updateMyProfile(profile)
    }
}
```

I want to do this using Coroutine Flow, Is this possible on Flow?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `BehaviorSubject`, which emits the most recently item at the time of subscription and then continues the sequence until complete. So basically it is a hot stream of data.

The similar behavior has [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/):

> A hotFlow that shares emitted values among all its collectors in a broadcast fashion, so that all collectors get all emitted values. A shared flow is called hot because its active instance exists independently of the presence of collectors.

For your case it will look something like the following:

```
class ProfileRepository(
    private val profileDao: ProfileDao
) {

    init {
        val profile = profileDao.getMyProfile()
        _myProfile.tryEmit(profile)
    }

    private val _myProfile = MutableSharedFlow<String>(replay = 1, extraBufferCapacity = 64)

    val myProfile: SharedFlow<Profile> = _myProfile

    fun updateMyProfile(profile: Profile) {
       _myProfile.tryEmit(profile)
    }
}

class ProfileViewModel(
    private val profileRepo: ProfileRepository
) {
    val myProfile = MutableLiveData<Profile>()
    
    fun loadMyProfile() = viewModelScope.launch {
        profileRepo.myProfile.collect {
            myProfile.postValue(it)
        }
    }
}
```

[`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) - Any coroutine launched in this scope is automatically canceled if the `ViewModel` is cleared. For `ViewModelScope`, use

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0 or higher.
```